# Why doesn't isupper without parentheses raise an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
string = 'ABcD'
for letter in string:
    if letter.isupper():
        print (letter,end='')
```

In the above code, the output is `ABD` 
But when I write the code without parentheses after `isupper`, like so:

```
string = 'ABcD'
for letter in string:
    if letter.isupper:
        print (letter,end='')
```

the output is `ABcD`.
Why doesn't python raise a syntax error here ; how does this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Why would you assume a syntax error here? This is valid syntax to refer to attributes.

Answer (score 3):

`isupper` is an attribute of the string `letter`, therefore Python is fine with you accessing it.

```
>>> letter = 'a'
>>> letter.isupper
<built-in method isupper of str object at 0x0000028258E80170>
```

It's the method `isupper` of the string. You did not call it (no `()`), but that's not a syntax error.

In a boolean context (`if letter.isupper`), Python checks whether `bool(letter.isupper)` is `True` or `False`.

```
>>> bool(letter.isupper)
True
```

Any method is "truthy" (`bool` returns `True`), so that's why the `if` block is entered.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth knowing that static analysis tools can be used to catch such mistakes. For example, with `pylint`:

```
test.py:2:0: W0125: Using a conditional statement with a constant value (using-constant-test)
```